# ERROR: Failed building wheel for dependency-injector, ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyduktape

Tags: python, django, dependency-injection, pipenv, requirements.txt

Failed to get both **dependency injector** and **pyduktape** in Django project requirements.txt. It asked to install Visual C++ 14.0 or greater but it is already there.

requirements.txt containts **dependency-injector==3.15.6** and **pyduktape==0.0.6**
Tried with Python 3.7, pip 21.3.1, and pipenv version 2021.5.29

```
Building wheels for collected packages: dependency-injector, pyduktape
  Building wheel for dependency-injector (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\users\yasiru\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\yasi
ru\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ai16fcys\\dependency-injector_e905913ba3f247b096ecaaf379d20b5b\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\yasiru\\AppData\\Loca
l\\Temp\\pip-install-ai16fcys\\dependency-injector_e905913ba3f247b096ecaaf379d20b5b\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path
.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(co
de, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\yasiru\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-23n96w5t'
       cwd: C:\Users\yasiru\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ai16fcys\dependency-injector_e905913ba3f247b096ecaaf379d20b5b\
  Complete output (13 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\dependency_injector
  copying src\dependency_injector\errors.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\dependency_injector
  copying src\dependency_injector\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\dependency_injector
  copying src\dependency_injector\containers.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\dependency_injector
  copying src\dependency_injector\providers.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\dependency_injector
  running build_ext
  building 'dependency_injector.containers' extension
  error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": [https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/][1]
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for dependency-injector


Running setup.py clean for dependency-injector
  Building wheel for pyduktape (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\users\yasiru\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\yasi
ru\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ai16fcys\\pyduktape_d628ca64f5d1498c83b77edf959e9080\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\yasiru\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\p
ip-install-ai16fcys\\pyduktape_d628ca64f5d1498c83b77edf959e9080\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) el
se io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'e
xec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\yasiru\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-gvd80r9x'
       cwd: C:\Users\yasiru\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ai16fcys\pyduktape_d628ca64f5d1498c83b77edf959e9080\
  Complete output (10 lines):
  c:\users\yasiru\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\setuptools\installer.py:30: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setuptools.installer is deprec
ated. Requirements should be satisfied by a PEP 517 installer.
    SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning,
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_ext
  cythoning pyduktape.pyx to pyduktape.c
  c:\users\yasiru\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-ai16fcys\pyduktape_d628ca64f5d1498c83b77edf959e9080\.eggs\cython-0.29.25-py3.7.egg\Cython\Compiler\Main.py:369: Fu
tureWarning: Cython directive 'language_level' not set, using 2 for now (Py2). This will change in a later release! File: C:\Users\yasiru\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-in
stall-ai16fcys\pyduktape_d628ca64f5d1498c83b77edf959e9080\pyduktape.pyx
    tree = Parsing.p_module(s, pxd, full_module_name)
  building 'pyduktape' extension
  error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyduktape
  Running setup.py clean for pyduktape
Failed to build dependency-injector pyduktape
Installing collected packages: pyduktape, dependency-injector
    Running setup.py install for pyduktape ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\yasiru\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\ya
siru\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ai16fcys\\pyduktape_d628ca64f5d1498c83b77edf959e9080\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\yasiru\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\
\pip-install-ai16fcys\\pyduktape_d628ca64f5d1498c83b77edf959e9080\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__)
else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"
'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\yasiru\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-wgnhusiv\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-
headers 'c:\users\yasiru\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\Include\pyduktape'
         cwd: C:\Users\yasiru\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ai16fcys\pyduktape_d628ca64f5d1498c83b77edf959e9080\
    Complete output (10 lines):
    c:\users\yasiru\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\setuptools\installer.py:30: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setuptools.installer is depr
ecated. Requirements should be satisfied by a PEP 517 installer.
      SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning,
    running install
    c:\users\yasiru\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py:37: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is de
precated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
      setuptools.SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning,
    running build
    running build_ext
    skipping 'pyduktape.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
    building 'pyduktape' extension
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\yasiru\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize;
 sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\yasiru\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ai16fcys\\pyduktape_d628ca64f5d1498c83b77edf959e9080\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Use
rs\\yasiru\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ai16fcys\\pyduktape_d628ca64f5d1498c83b77edf959e9080\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__fil
e__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();
exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\yasiru\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-wgnhusiv\install-record.txt' --single-version-extern
ally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\yasiru\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\Include\pyduktape' Check the logs for full command output.'''


  [1]: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
```